# Where can I host (free) a stereo mp4 file to use in a stereo video webVR tag

Tags: video, aframe, stereo-3d

Is there a free place to store my equirectangular up/down mp4 video so that it can be accessed in src= "file.mp4"?

I now have the stereo video "working" using [Oscarmarinmiro's](https://github.com/oscarmarinmiro/aframe-stereo-component) solution. Except that my web host is serving my video too too slowly.

I tried Google Drive, Google photos, and MS One drive, but after getting the "file link," the video does not play in a video tag (regular or webVR).  It does not seem to be a link to a playable mp4 file.

Is there another host/file server with access to the mp4 file; or a way to get a link to the original (or playable) mp4 file in Drive, Photo or One-drive.

Answer (score 1):

Vimeo might be a good host for you. Vimeo supports top/bottom [stereo video](https://help.vimeo.com/hc/en-us/articles/115001877167-Uploading-360-video), and deals with all the transcoding to multiple formats & hosting of the video.

**[Here is a Vimeo WebVR demo](https://github.com/vimeo/vimeo-webvr-demo)** for A-frame which leverages React to dynamically stream a stereo 360 video and leverages [oscarmarinmiro stereo solution](https://github.com/oscarmarinmiro/aframe-stereo-component). Once you have it all setup, all you have to do is point your Vimeo tag to your Vimeo video URL:

```
<Vimeo url="https://vimeo.com/244123293" />
```

*Note: Unfortunately this is not a free solution. It's free to host a video on Vimeo, but in order to get access to the file URL, Vimeo requires you have a membership.*